# How to use output parameter with other columns names in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple table with columns - id, name, and salary.

I want to get the name, salary and annual salary by id using a stored procedure.

I thought of creating a simple stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetDetails
    @id int,
    @annualSal int out
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        name, salary, 
        @annualSal = (salary * 12) 
    FROM 
        tblPrac 
    WHERE 
        id = @id
END
```

But I'm getting an error:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

If this qs is already asked please give me the link and I'll delete this qs. I searched but I think I'm missing the key word. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to search the error on Internet?

Comment: The error message clearly stating that, you can't do Assign & Selecting in a single statement.

Comment: As the error says, you can't combine the two operations, but in this case it seems like pretty superfluous use of an output paramater. Since whatever is calling the procedure is most likely reading the first two columns, why not just use a third column "AnnualSalary", and have whatever is calling it obtain the annual salary through this rather than an output parameter?

Comment: @GarethD is right. No need for the `@annualSal int out` paramter

Comment: Yes, I can select it as a column and give it an alias name but I was thinking what is going wrong if I use the output parameter.

Comment: Why are you trying to use an output parameter for one of the values and not for the other two (Name, Salary)? You need to either use 3 output parameters, or 3 select columns, you can't mix and match. This is why you are getting an error.

Comment: Now it's quite clear. Output parameter and select operation cannot be applied simultaneously. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stuff mixed so you need to choose between 2 possibilities

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetDetails
  @id int,
  @name varchar(100) out,
  @salary decimal(16,2) out,
  @annualSal decimal(16,2) out
AS
BEGIN
   set nocount on

   SELECT  @name = name, 
           @salary = salary, 
           @annualSal = (salary * 12) 
   FROM    tblPrac 
   WHERE   id = @id
END
```

or this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetDetails
  @id int
AS
BEGIN
   set nocount on

   SELECT  name, 
           salary, 
           (salary * 12) as anualSal
   FROM    tblPrac 
   WHERE   id = @id
END
```

Comment: Yes I have to either select all as columns or use output parameter for all columns.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an `OUTPUT` parameter. You can simply query like this -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetDetails
    @id int
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT Name, Salary, (Salary*12) AS AnnualSalary FROM tblPrac WHERE id = @id
    END
```

Comment: Actually, I was trying to use the output parameter, I know using the alias can give me the same result.

Comment: If you really need to use an `OUTPUT` parameter, then you will need to get the value for it in an independent query. You cannot select some other columns as well as populate that parameter in the same query

Comment: only thing that is missing here is the 'set nocount on' statement

Comment: @GuidoG - Added. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to store the data and separate the operations (as the error message is explaining):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetDetails
(
    @id int,
    @annualSal int out
)
AS
BEGIN;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
    (
        [name] VARCHAR(12)
       ,[salary] DECIMAL(9,2)
    );

    INSERT INTO @DataSource ([name], [salary])
    SELECT  name, salary
    FROM tblPrac 
    WHERE id = @id;

    SELECT [name]
          ,[salary]
    FROM @DataSource;

    SELECT @annualSal = 12 * [salary]
    FROM @DataSource;

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    RETURN;
END;
```